# Ejercicio de vectores

Tags: c

Como sigo con este ejercicio

El dueño de la posada quiere saber cuántas son las personas alojadas en el lugar
Dado un vector en cual las posiciones simulan ser habitaciones distintas y en cada una de ellas se encuentra 
una cierta cantidad de huéspedes, se pide crear una función que devuelva el total solicitado

```
int contar_huespedes(int habitaciones[MAX_HABITACIONES], int cantidad_habitaciones){
 for(int i= 0; i<=cantidad_habitaciones, i++){
    printf("Dame la cantidad de habitaciones", cantidad_habitaciones+1);
    scanf ("%i",&habitaciones[MAX_HABITACIONES]);
 }    
}

int main(){
int cantidad_habitaciones=0; 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola! Cuál es el problema que tienes con el código que nos compartes?

Comment: No sé como seguir, ahi me quede

Comment: Eso no es una pregunta sino una afirmación. Por otro lado, no tiene demasiado sentido que una función que se llama `contar_huespedes`, y remarco lo de **contar** se dedique a **rellenar** el vector... El ejercicio consta de dos partes: Rellenar un vector de datos y contar los valores que figuran en dicho vector. Eso son dos bucles: uno para rellenar y otro para contar. Por lo demás, lo dicho, para que te demos soluciones tienes que hacer preguntas, no afirmaciones.